# Using Special Fonts with Chrome, Apostrophe doesn't work

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, webfonts

I'm using this css font family:

```
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
```

I'm on Windows 7 and using Chrome  33.0.1750.146 m.

When I use an apostrophe, it comes out looking like a letter I lowercase with an accent.
The source is correct, and if you copy it, it's the right char...why does it not display correctly? I don't want this experience for other users visiting my site. The site is built on Wordpress.

Comment: My workaround was to use html entities, but is that really the solution? seems annoying.

Comment: Which apostrophe are you using? Please include the character into your question. Which of the fonts in used?

Comment: Using this apostrophe => '
I listed the fonts above.

Comment: That’s the Ascii apostrophe U+0027, so it can hardly cause encoding problems, and it should appear in practically any normal font. The most probable explanation is thus that some of the fonts in your computer is broken, corrupted. What is the font actually used by the browser in your computer? What happens if you test that font in an editor and type the Ascii apostrophe?